# Using MySQL triggers in AWS to empty cache on updates and inserts

Tags: mysql, triggers, amazon-web-services, redis

I am building an architecture on AWS with several EC2 instances as webservers and a central MySQL database (RDS). The EC2 instances have Redis installed for caching single db rows. When a row changes in MySQL, I want every instance to update the corresponding cache entries too.

What is the best way to do this in the AWS enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a queue server (amazon SQS, redis pubsub, etc) you could put an entry onto a queue for each record you want expired, and have a worker listening to the queue and when it gets a message to tell it which record to invalidate it will connect to cache and expire that record.

This works if you have one cache server or many, you just need one worker for each cache server that you have, or one worker that can connect to each cache server. Many workers is more scalable.

Comment: Thank you for this sugestions, that's exactly what I am trying to do. But how to push a message onto a queue within a SQL trigger?

Comment: @Thomas do you have to use a Trigger? Can you do it outside of mysql at the code level?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use triggers for this. Ensure things are properly committed (as opposed to rolled back), and *then* flush from within the application layer.

If you don't, you can have a scenario where concurrent requests are re-filling the cache with the old data (since they don't see the new data yet) as it'll get deleted from the cache in your SQL trigger.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, that there is more then one application with access to the database. My inital idea was to use Amazons SNS when a trigger is fired to send notifications to all registered caching instances. But i don't know how to implement this in RDS.

Comment: If you really want it as a trigger you could arguably extend mysql and wrap libmemcached in SQL functions (such a lib probably exists already), but having played with pg-memcached on my end, I'd seriously advise against doing so. Dealing with a cache that holds partially corrupt values for hours is a lot worse than having partially invalid cached data for a split second.

Comment: Meant libredis, or whatever it's called in your case. For what it's worth, I deal with trickier cache flush needs in postgres by filling a (memory based, unlogged) table that ties key references using the transaction id. Sadly, a cursory search reveals this is [not possible](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12866) in mysql as is - though the [connection id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function%5Fconnection-id) might be a good enough proxy.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Can the libmemcached/redis extension deal with several independent cache instances? The EC2 webserver instances each have their own independet redis instance running. My idea was to use SNS and do the flushing on the instances by myself. For this i would need to do a POST request to the SNS RESTful webservice. Could this somehow be done inside of a trigger?

Comment: Again, I think your best bet is to fill some kind of needs_flush table. That can be easily done with a trigger. *After* the commit is done, process them one by one and discard them. Flushing *before* the commit is asking for two sorts of issues: cache poisoning and deadlocks in case of writes that need to concurrently lock rows because transactions last too long.

Comment: Having a table for flushes is a good suggestion. My initial idea was to push messages about changes to the cache instances instead of let the instances pull from the database. Of course, the call to the webservice should be done in an after-change trigger.